# "zip" не является внутренней или внешней командой

Tags: python

Код:

```
import os
import time

# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['"Z:\\Новая папка\\img296.jpg"', '"Z:\\Новая папка"']
# Заметьте, что для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.

target_dir = 'Z:\\Backup'

# Создаем архив
# Имя архива - текущее дата и время
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ''.join(source))

print(zip_command)

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
     print('Копирование выполнено успешно в', target)
else:
     print('Копирование не удалось!')
```

При запуске кода через PyCharm получаю:

```
C:\Python\python.exe C:/Python/PyCharm/backup_ver1.py
zip -qr Z:\Backup\20190702182832.zip "C:\IQIYI Video"C:\Python
"zip" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Копирование не удалось!
Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

При запуске командной строки или через терминал PyCharm получаю:

```
C:\Python\PyCharm>python backup_ver1.py
zip -qr Z:\Backup\20190702175052.zip "C:\IQIYI Video"C:\Python
"zip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Копирование не удалось!
```

Тогда начал искать проблему. Наткнулся в книге вот на это:

```
Будем использовать стандартную команду zip, имеющуюся по умолчанию в любом
стандартном дистрибутиве GNU/Linux. Пользователи Windows могут установить её
со страницы проекта GnuWin32 и добавить “C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin” к 
системной переменной окружения PATH, аналогично тому, как мы это делали для 
самой команды “python”.
```

Тогда скачиваю GnuWin32:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К системной переменной окружения PATH добавил путь к zip:

```
C:\Python\;C:\Python\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\zip.exe
```

После этого снова запускаю программу:

```
C:\Python\python.exe C:/Python/PyCharm/backup_ver1.py
zip -qr Z:\Backup\20190702184356.zip "C:\IQIYI Video"C:\Python
К"zip" опирование не удалось!
Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
```

И через терминал:

```
C:\Python\PyCharm>python backup_ver1.py
zip -qr Z:\Backup\20190702184630.zip "C:\IQIYI Video"C:\Python
"zip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
Копирование не удалось!
```

Если к системной переменной окружения PATH добавить такой путь (без zip.exe):

```
C:\Python\;C:\Python\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\
```

То программа MyCharm выдает:

```
C:\Python\PyCharm>python backup_ver1.py
zip -qr Z:\Backup\20190702213153.zip "C:\IQIYI Video"C:\Python

zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -qr Z:\Backup\20190702213153.zip . -i 
C:\IQIYI VideoC:\Python)
Копирование не удалось!
```

Только что обнаружил. Чтобы скопировать несколько файлов или каталогов нужно поставить между ними пробел:

```
source = ['"Z:\\Новая папка\\img296.jpg"', ' ', '"Z:\\Новая папка"']
```

Или пробел перед .join(source):

```
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))
```

Тогда все сработает.

```
C:\Python\python.exe C:/Python/PyCharm/backup_ver1.py
zip -qr Z:\Backup\20190702234443.zip "Z:\Новая папка\img296.jpg" "Z:\Новая папка"
Копирование выполнено успешно в Z:\Backup\20190702234443.zip

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Спасибо всем за ответы!

Comment: В `PATH` надо добавлять каталог, в котором находиться zip.exe. После добавления терминал нужно перезапустить.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Может я не догоняю, но я же уже указал каталог, в котором находится zip.exe (C:\Python\;C:\Python\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\zip.exe). И после перезапуска все остается также.

Comment: Путь к каталогу, а не файлу - `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Ок. Я указываю путь к каталогу (C:\Python\;C:\Python\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\). Перезапускаю. Теперь он выводит следующее: zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -qr Z:\Backup\20190702213153.zip . -i C:\IQIYI VideoC:\Python)
Копирование не удалось!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev [вы не против](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1147800/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-zip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/1147838#1147838)?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica конечно не против.

Answer (score 1):

В переменную PATH надо добавлять пути, а не сами программы. Попробуйте установить:

```
C:\Python\;C:\Python\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\
```