# Ошибка "'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: python, zip

Читаю книгу 'Byte of python' , и патаюсь решить задачу из главы 13.1. Но вылезает ошибка , можете ли помочь решить её?

Работаю в PyCharm. 
**Вот ошибка которая выдаётся:**  
'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. 
**Вот сам код:**

```
import os
import time

# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\\Code']
# Заметьте, что для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.

# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.
target_dir = 'E:\\Backup' # Подставьте тот путь, который вы будете использовать.

# 3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив.
# 4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время.
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

# Запускаем создание резервной копии
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
   print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
   print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

**Вот что происходит когда запускаю код**

```
 'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
 Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ
```

[Правильно ли я сделала? в самом последнем совете](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PygSt.png)

Comment: Забыла уточнить. У меня Windows 10

Comment: @Alex Что? Извини, я начинающий програмист и совсем не поняла первое предложение...

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить команду в командной строке, а не через питон.

Comment: на сайте этой книги есть несколько вариантов этой задачи, попробуйте другой. https://python.swaroopch.com/problem_solving.html

Comment: @вася Весь код? Можешь подсказать как это делать?

Comment: @ВикторияМолотова напишите `print(zip_command)`, а то, что напечатает, попробуйте выполнить в `cmd.exe`. Если и там не работает, то проблема не в питоне.

Comment: Это примерно 38-й вопрос с этим кодом из книги и из них 25-й с этой ошибкой на этом сайте. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998585/zip-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b9

Comment: @вася     Вот что выходит  *Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Lenovo>print(zip_command)
'print' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Lenovo>python
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Lenovo>print(zip_command)
'print' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

Comment: @ВикторияМолотова посмотрите ссылку, которую Эникейщик привёл.

Comment: @вася Вот что выходит сейчас: 'zip -qr Z:\Backup\20200701175345.zip C:\My Documents   C:\Code
'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Копирование не удалось!'

Comment: Может чем то это поможет, в PyCharm у меня подсвечивается желтым 'sep' в команде 'os.sep'

Comment: @Эникейщик Этот чертов вопрос задавали уже раз сто.

Comment: @Эникейщик **_ДАВАЙТЕ НАКОНЕЦ КТО-НИБУДЬ НАПИШЕТ ОТВЕТ ЧТОБ БЫЛ ДУПЛИКАТ !!!_**

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Да, давно пора!

Comment: @Эникейщик Жалко у тебя нет золотой метки.

Comment: @Эникейщик Я сделал общим, проголосуйте, чтоб можно было задупликатить все эти вопросы к черту.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ay??

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica в пути был.

Comment: @Эникейщик ok..

Comment: Вопрос решён. Вот ссылка на ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149323/Нету-файла-zip-exe-в-gnuwin32/1149335?noredirect=1#comment1990942_1149335

Answer (score 1):

Sergey Gornostaev:

> В PATH надо добавлять каталог, в котором находиться zip.exe. После добавления терминал нужно перезапустить.

Comment: Как это можно сделать?

Comment: @ВикторияМолотова https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html

Comment: Сделала как в инструкции, всё равно не работает. Но может я просто это не там сделала? Можешь проверить правильность моих действий в прикрепленом скриншоте к посту?

Comment: @ВикторияМолотова Блин извини, но я в винде вообще не шарю. Я на маке (и в линуксе тоже разбираюсь). Задай другой вопрос.

Comment: @ВикторияМолотова https://github.com/wp-cli/dist-archive-command/issues/22

Comment: @ВикторияМолотова https://superuser.com/questions/506828/zip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or

Comment: в том посте что ты мне скинул вот что советуют: 'Скопируйте исполняемый путь 7-zip и добавьте его к значению переменной среды PATH' Дак вот , что такое путь 7-zip , где и как его скопировать?

Comment: @ВикторияМолотова https://superuser.com/questions/201371/create-zip-folder-from-the-command-line-windows

Comment: С этой проблемой я маюсь уже пару дней. И на сегодня я уже устала. Завтра попробую советы из той ссылкой которую ты мне прислал

Comment: @ВикторияМолотова ok!

Comment: Извини, даже с переводчиком я не поняла что написано в последней ссылке которую ты мне скинув. При поиске ошибки в YouTube мне высветилась ошибка 'not recognized as internal or external Command' . Я исправила эту ошибку но старая сохранилась. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Скачайте zip для виндовс здесь https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/zip/3.0/zip-3.0-setup.exe/download?use_mirror=kumisystems. При установке, когда вам покажет Select Additional Tasks, поставте галочку Download sources и нажмите next. После того как установите, вам скачается еще один файл "zip-3.0-src". Переместите его в папку GnuWin32. После етого зайдите в Environment Variables и добавьте в path путь к файлам, что установились ранее. Пример: C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin. После етого попробуйте запустить програму. Если програма делалась по примеру с книги "A byte of python" вам может показать проблему такого рода: Nothing to do! (try: zip -qr E:\Backup\200805154140.zip . -i C:\My DocumentsC:\Code). Тогда вам стоить добавить E:\Backup\200805154140.zip . -i C:\My DocumentsC:\Code в zip_command.