# Проблема с задачей python по созданию резервной копии

Tags: python

Читаю книгу A Byte of Python. Первая задача "Создание резервной копии". Возникает проблема, прочитал много постов, но к сожалению решение своей проблемы так и не нашёл.

Установил zip как и указано. В cmd команда "zip" отображается и через cmd я могу создать резервный архив с файлами.
Пробовал с 7Zip, указывал файл напрямую, но всё равно ошибка.
В переменную PATH добавил необходимое. Ниже оставил код.

```
import os
import time

# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['C:\\Code']
# Для имен, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.

# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.
target_dir = 'D:\\Backend'

# 3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив.
# 4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время.
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

# Запускаем создание резервной копии
print(zip_command)
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')

zip -qr D:\Backend\20200815125347.zip C:\Code
Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://python.swaroopch.com/problem_solving.html  это сайт автора книги и там несколько решений это проблемы

Comment: Это примерно 132 вопрос на этом сайте по этому коду из этой книги. Думаю, что пора бы с автора книги взыскать за моральные страдания.

Comment: @Интик Прочитал, но к сожалению на сайте не указано решение моей проблемы. У меня впринципе не запускается "архивирование".

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1147800/398802

Comment: @dIm0n Я уже просто не понимаю что не так. С 7Zip, просто с ZIP в CMD у меня создаётся архив, копируются данные всё в порядке. А в Sublime Text выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Используйте `subprocess` и `pathlib`

Answer (score 2):

По совету использовал subprocess и всё получилось. Всё также прекрасно работает и с 7Zip.

```
import subprocess
import time

# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список.
source = ['C:\\py']
# Для имен, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
# двойные кавычки внутри строки.

# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва.
target_dir = '"D:\\Backup"'

# 3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив.
# 4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время.
target = target_dir + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

# Запускаем создание резервной копии
print(zip_command)
if subprocess.call(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужна такая рабочая программа, то можно ничего не устанавливать и использовать стандартный модуль `zipfile`:

```
import os
import time
import zipfile


sources = ['C:\\Code']

target_dir = 'D:\\Backend'

target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'
files = []

for source in sources:                    #Ищем
    for i in os.walk(source):             #абсолютные
        for file in i[2]:                 #имена
            files.append(i[0]+'\\'+file)  #всех файлов

try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(target, 'w') as z: # Записываем
        for file in files:                  # всё
            z.write(file)                   # в архив
except:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
else:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
```