# Не могу проверить установлен ли GnuWin32

Tags: python

```
import os

import time


source = ['D:\\Python', 'D:\\Project']

target_dir = 'D:\\backup'

target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H') + '.zip'

zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ''.join(source))

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Я учу Пайтон по книге 'A Byte of Python' и у меня есть проблема с тем что я не могу проверить установил ли я GnuWin32(Я работаю на редакторе PyCharm).Я смотрел другие ответы но мне так и не помогло
[image: Вот скрин]

Comment: Ну у вас на скриншоте открыта папка GnuWin32 - значит видимо установлен. В чем вопрос-то?

Comment: Проблема в том что я код не работет.Я не знаю как решить и подумал что правильно ли он установлен.

Comment: Если код не работает, укажите конкретную ошибку в вопросе. Если что-то пробовали - укажите что именно пробовали (например, пробовали ли прописать путь до директории bin в переменной окружения PATH?). Рекомендую также ознакомиться с [похожими вопросами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=gnuwin32+zip+%5Bpython%5D), например, с этим: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/998585/1365

Comment: Понял спасибо мне помогло)